# 403 Forbidden error message on Debian 7

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

This is a Debian 7 server, hosting one web domain. Getting 403 error when trying to reach the page.

Apache is www-data.

DocumentRoot is /var/www/domain.com

```
/var/www is root:www-data
/var/www/domain.com is www-data:www-data  drwxr-xr-x
```

The virtualhost config is:

```
     Options -Indexes
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
```

Where else can I check to look for possible issues?

Comment: Check Apache’s access and error log.

Comment: All I see is "client denied by server configuration"

Comment: So what URL exactly are yoy trying to access? If it is a request for a directory, does that have an index file (anything configured to be automatically picked by `DirectoryIndex`)? After that, check your httpd.conf for additional DENY directives.

Comment: I'm trying to access www.domain.com and there's an index.php file there. I've also tried index.html and doesn't work either.

Comment: That’s an error message you can google for.

Comment: I did. I was able to resolve things up until this point.